# Не подгружаются данные с Firebase

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

При попытке вывести данные из Firebase выдается ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?
P.S. Если вручную формировать данные, то все работает.

Лог ошибок:

> `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.gukov.guap, PID: 3760                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.gukov.guap.DirectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.example.gukov.guap.SearchFragment$1.onChildAdded(SearchFragment.java:122)

Код адаптера DirectionAdapter:

```
public class DirectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirectionAdapter.DirectionViewHolder> {
private List<Direction> directionList;

public DirectionAdapter(List<Direction> directionList) {
    this.directionList = directionList;
}

@Override
public DirectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new DirectionViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.direction, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DirectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Direction direction = directionList.get(position);
    holder.textViewDirectionTitle.setText(direction.directionTitle);
    holder.textViewDirectionCount.setText(direction.directionCount);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return directionList.size();
}

class DirectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewDirectionTitle, textViewDirectionCount;

    public DirectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        textViewDirectionTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirectionTitle);
        textViewDirectionCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirectionCount);
    }

}}
```

Код Direction:

```
public class Direction {

String directionCount;
String directionTitle, key;

public Direction() {

}

public Direction(String directionCount, String directionTitle, String key) {
    this.directionCount = directionCount;
    this.directionTitle = directionTitle;
    this.key = key;
}}
```

Код SearchFragment:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DirectionAdapter adapter;
List<Direction> directionList;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private FirebaseUser user;

public SearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // инициализация FirebaseAuth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("directions");


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);

    fabAdd.setOnClickListener(this);


    directionList = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext());
    lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);



    DirectionAdapter adapter = new DirectionAdapter(directionList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();


    return rootView;
}

//если вручную заполнить
//    private void createResult() {
//
//        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//            directionList.add(new Direction("title","key","12"));
//        }
//    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fabAdd:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddMeetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// Проверка, залогинен ли уже текущий пользователь
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}

// обновление пользовательского интерфейся
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        //
    } else {
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fabAdd).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void updateList() {
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            directionList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Direction.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Direction model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Direction.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);
            directionList.set(index, model);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Direction model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Direction.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);
            directionList.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private int getItemIndex(Direction direction) {
    int index = -1;

    for (int i= 0; i < directionList.size(); i++) {
        if (directionList.get(i).key.equals(direction.key)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас адаптер объявлен как локальная переменная внутри метода `onCreateView()`. При обращении из `updateList()` он видит другой адаптер, которому Вы не присвоили значение. Исправьте это место:

```
...
adapter = new DirectionAdapter(directionList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

Т.к. Вы создате повторно объект `DirectionAdapter`, то первый, который объявлен в классе, соответственно, равен `null`. Надеюсь, что это просто невнимательность.

Comment: Спасибо и правда не заметил. Но заметил еще одну проблему: в эмуляторе все нормально загружается, отображается. А когда устанавливаю приложение на реальный телефон - оно вылетает при попытке зайти на этот фрагмент с данными с firebase. Телефон и версия ОС такие же как в эмуляторе. Не понимаю, что может быть не так?

Comment: @СергейГуков лог ошибки в студию

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.gukov.guap, PID: 9853
                                                                      com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.gukov.guap.Direction`

Comment: @СергейГуков в классе `Direction` сделайте либо публичные поля, либо get методы.

Comment: @СергейГуков + еще можно прописать `implements Serializable` у `Direction` и добавить строку `-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** { *; }` в proguard-rules.pro, подставив нужный путь. Это тоже может помочь.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал через get методы